# Can anyone suggest a jQuery shoutbox plugin that writes to an SQL database?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, chat

I need a sort of chatbox for a project I'm working on and I don't fancy getting into the nitty-gritty of it myself. Can anyone recommend a good plugin?

My requirements are...

- Auto-update with jQuery for anyone viewing the page, not just the user.
- Writes to an SQL database, not a text file.
- Written in the most recent jQuery.

I looked at one from [Code Forest](http://www.codeforest.net/making-a-shoutbox-with-php-mysql-and-jquery) and one from [AjaxDaddy](http://www.ajaxdaddy.com/demo-jquery-shoutbox.html) but the former did not update for everyone and the latter was written in dated jQuery and wrote to a text file.

Any other suggestions? Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1):

On the first link you tried, everybody get updated but the refresh happens every 15 seconds.

That could easily be changed inside refresh_shoutbox function in this line:

```
// recurring refresh every 15 seconds
setInterval("refresh_shoutbox()", 15000);
```

where 15000 is a number of miliseconds.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thanks for posting your answer! Please be sure to read the [FAQ on Self-Promotion](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#promotion) carefully. Also note that it is *required* that you post a disclaimer every time you link to your own site/product. LittleBobbyTables removed the link to your site, as it did not seem important to the answer itself. This way, your post does not seem like 'spam'.

Answer (score 0):

This one is more up-to-date: http://yensdesign.com/2009/01/create-a-shoutbox-using-php-and-ajax-jquery/

Edit: This one is payed, but also working: http://codecanyon.net/item/shoutcloud-flexible-phpajax-shoutboxchat/full_screen_preview/125018 (no affiliate, no connection or what so ever!)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It doesn't look like the former updates for everyone, though.

Answer (score 0):

I've used QShout a few times in the past. It works fine, is somewhat modern (jq 1.4) and is fairly easy to extend.

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/QShout